# fabric-composer quick-start failed on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I'm trying to follow [the Fabric Composer Quickstart](https://fabric-composer.github.io/installing/quickstart.html) but failed.

Could you give me hints?

When I tried "**sudo npm install**", the script was completed with a few warnings.

```
npm WARN lifecycle getting-started@1.0.0~preinstall: cannot run in wd %s %s (wd=%s) getting-started@1.0.0 composer --version || echo 'Please first run npm install -g composer-cli'  /<directory>/sample-applications/packages/getting-started
npm WARN lifecycle getting-started@1.0.0~install: cannot run in wd %s %s (wd=%s) getting-started@1.0.0 scripts/download-hyperledger.sh && scripts/start-hyperledger.sh && npm run deployNetwork /<directory>/sample-applications/packages/getting-started
```

When I tried "**sudo composer network list -n digitalproperty-network --enrollId WebAppAdmin --enrollSecret DJY27pEnl16d**",

```
List business network digitalproperty-network
2017-03-21T22:44:47.360Z ERROR   FSConnectionProfileStore :load()                    Failed to loaded connection profile defaultProfile {"0":{"stack":["{Error}ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '<directory>.composer-connection-profiles/defaultProfile/connection.json' Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '<directory>.composer-connection-profiles/defaultProfile/connection.json'","    at Error (native)"]}}$
Failed to load connection profile defaultProfile
Command completed successfully.
```

I use

```
Ubuntu: 16.04
docker: 1.13.1
docker-compose: 1.11.2
node: v6.10.0
npm: 4.4.4
git: 2.11.0
composer:
composer-cli                   v0.5.5
composer-admin                 v0.5.5
composer-client                v0.5.5
composer-common                v0.5.5
composer-runtime-hlf           v0.5.5
composer-connector-hlf         v0.5.5
```

It looks like I have .composer-connection-profiles/defaultProfile/ direcotry but the directory don't have connection.js

How can we solve the problem? can i prepare connection.js manually?

Thank you!

Comment: I tried to use Ubuntu 14.04 and used prereqs-ubuntu.sh which is prepared by Fabric-composser. Still I have an error which says "Error: Failed to load connector module "composer-connector-hlf" for connection profile "defaultProfile""

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem occurs when you run the npm install using sudo.
it shouldn't be necessary to run the commands as root so try again without using sudo and see if that helps.

Comment: Yes you're right! I found "/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/grpc_node.node" was not  created and I rebuilt composer-cli with --unsafe-perm and I'm good now! But you're right I should not have used sudo in the first place....

Answer (score 0):

This solves the problem `npm install composer-connector-hlf`